# Getting by command line the class names of a C++ library

Tags: c++, class, terminal, command, shared-libraries

Is there any way to find all C++ class names (or al least file names) used to make a C++ library? Similar to 'nm' command to find all methods.

Thanks.

Comment: Static or dynamic lib? Which OS?

Comment: Search "demangle C++ class names"

Comment: Demangling can be make using nm -C option, but it also shows method names, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
objdump <library> --dwarf=pubtypes
```

It gives all class names in my case.

There are other options you can pass along the `--dwarf` parameter so you can look that up too if is helps.